# Program starts itself after being task killed

Tags: bash, powershell, taskkill

I have this software PC2Control which I want to taskkill. **(Also I don't want to uninstall that)**

```
taskkill /f /t /im PCControl2Client.exe :: success
```

But after like 1 second, it automatically starts again. I think it could be some **Windows event**.

#### This is one way to go, but its not really good way.

```
while($true)
{
    $find =  tasklist | findstr "PCControl";
    if($find -eq $null)
    {
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 1;
    }
    else
    {
        taskkill /F /IM PCControl2ClientService.exe /T;
        taskkill /F /IM PCControl2ClientUser.exe /T;
        taskkill /F /IM PCControl2Client.exe /T;
    }
}
```

Any ideas how to stop it?

#### EDIT

Found it for those who are wondering.

It was service with recovery options (thanks to Toni), which you can found by typing `service` in search bar or powershell `get-service`

This will disable all recovery options using cmd.

```
SC failure <ServiceName> actions=""/1000/""/1000/""/1000 reset=86400
```

Comment: What is your question? Stop the process from restarting, or improve your `while` loop code?

Comment: its probably a service with configured recovery options. as you are on powershell take a look at ```get-process``` and ```stop-process```. does ```get-service | ?{$_.BinaryPathName -match 'PCControl2ClientService'}``` give you something back?

Comment: Thanks! I found it, I knew it was somewhere, but didn't know where. You helped me there with the keyword `service`, thanks!